# Using System.Drawing.DrawLine to draw multiple lines/shapes from console application

Tags: c#, bitmap, console-application

I am writing a program for my work that will take a custom directional code format and draw shapes based on the code given and save the result to an image.

Example:

> **SQR=W10 S10 E10 N10$.**

Would give an output of a 10x10 square shape on an image (*N, S, E, and W* are directions).

I know how to get this done using **OnPaint** with a WPF application, but I need this to be done through a console application. I have all the data parsed and in classes and collections so all I have to do is draw. but I am having trouble getting past the memory issue; it only draws one line at a time and doesn't save the previous lines.

The code I have partially drawing is:

```
Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 2);
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(xMax, yMax);

using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
{
    graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, new Rectangle(0, 0, xMax, yMax));

    foreach (Line line in lines)
    {
        graphics.DrawLine(pen, line.start, line.end);
    }
}

bmp.Save("test.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Here is the code I have using **DrawLines**, instead:

```
Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 2);
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(xMax, yMax);

using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
{
    graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, new Rectangle(0, 0, xMax, yMax));

    Point[] pts = new Point[lines.Count];
    int i = 0;

    pts[0] = lines[0].start; // This sets the starting point.

    foreach (Line line in lines)
    {
        pts[i] = line.end;
        i++;
    }

    graphics.DrawLines(pen, pts);
}

bmp.Save("test.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

And here is my **Line** class:

```
class Line
{
    public Point start { get; set; }
    public Point end { get; set; }
}
```

This is what my List of points looks like right before drawing:

[image]

#### What are my options for doing this, using System.Drawing and a Console Application, and allowing it to save all lines to the resulting image?

Comment: Do use the DrawLines method for better quality! It takes an array of points, so you should rewrite the code that creates the lines. Other than that the code looks fine. I assume you did include the necessary references..? Can you show the `line` class?

Comment: I tried DrawLines also and I still only get that same line. I can show the Line class (it's adapted from a different route I was taking so it's not perfect but it should still work)

Comment: I suspect your data. - Btw: What I meant was to collect all points ina List<Point> and the draw them all in one go: DrawLines(pen, points.ToArray());

Comment: I'll look at the Line collection write before drawing.

Comment: But the DrawLines is only meant to draw consecutive ie connected lines! If you need seperate lines your original code is as good as it gets!

Comment: They should be connected. I posted the data in the **List<Points>** right before **DrawLines** gets called.

Comment: Ah, now we're getting to the issue: You are drawing in the negative. We need to shift the Graphics objet. I'' post an answer, if you want me to..

Comment: Yes please do! I can't find any issues similar online so it will at least provide help to others also!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what you need to change:

First we transform the lines into a `List<T>` of `Points`:

```
List<Point> points = lines.Select(x => x.start).ToList();
points.Add(lines.Last().end);
```

(I always try to avoid arrays, Lists are so much nicer to work with..)

Now we determine the minima for the x and y values:

```
int minX = points.Select(x => x.X).Min();
int minY = points.Select(x => x.Y).Min();
```

Then we shift the `graphics` viewport to bring them all in:

```
graphics.TranslateTransform( -minX, -minY);
```

Now we can draw them all in one go:

```
graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias; // optional
using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 2)
{ LineJoin = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LineJoin.Round })
    graphics.DrawLines(pen, points.ToArray());
```

A few notes:

- I didn't check the maxima! If those are too large we still will lose some lines or line segments..
- One big advantage of `DrawLines`: It will work fine with semi-transparent pens i.e. the overlapping ends will be drawn correctly.
- I have moved the pen creation to the drawing; feel free to put it where you want but make sure to **dispose** of the `Pen` when you are done with it.
- I have also set a `LineJoin`; do play with them! You will see the effects when the pen widths get really large..

Comment: Drawing much better now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Show the code where you populate the `lines` collection.  Put a breakpoint in that code and inspect your list of lines and verify that there are more than one line in the collection.

I used the following code (with your Line class) and it worked just fine and drew all the lines.

```
void Main()
{
    int xMax, yMax;
    xMax = 512;
    yMax = 512;

    //Create a list of lines to draw.
    var lines = new List<Line>
    {
        new Line
        {
            Start = new Point(5, 5),
            End =  new Point(50, 50)
        },
        new Line
        {
            Start = new Point(100, 20),
            End =  new Point(50, 90)
        },
        new Line
        {
            Start = new Point(35, 75),
            End =  new Point(500, 400)
        },
    };

    //Declare the Bitmap, Graphics, and Pen in a using block so
    //they are all disposed properly when finished.        
    using (var bmp = new Bitmap(xMax, yMax))
    using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    using (var pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 2))
    {
        graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Green, new Rectangle(0, 0, xMax, yMax));

        foreach (Line line in lines)
        {
            graphics.DrawLine(pen, line.Start, line.End);
        }

        bmp.Save(@"g:\test\test.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }
}
```

Note:  Always be sure to dispose your graphics objects (Graphics, Pens, and Bitmaps) so you don't leak resources.  The best way is to use a `using` block.

**I see I was late to the party.  I'll leave this here anyway in case it helps someone else.

Comment: The error was with my points being in the negatives so they weren't showing on the resulting image. Thank you for the answer, though! I'm sure it will help others!

Comment: @Chris-dunaway Interesting, how's that you're able to use `Graphics` in a console application? When I used `Graphics.FromImage()`, I get an error stating: *Encapsulates GDI+ surface. This class cannot be inherited*...